# Widening Pandas Data Frame, Similar to Pivot or Stack/Unstack

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

My problem is probably best explained with an example:

What I have:

```
ID0,ID1,Time,Data0,Data1
 1   1   10  'A'    93
 1   2   10  'A'    55
 1   1   12  'A'    88
 1   2   12  'B'    66
 2   3   102 'C'    14
 2   4   102 'A'    22
 2   4   112 'D'    15
 2   3   112 'B'    43
```

What I would like:

```
ID0,ID1,Time,Data0,Data1,Data0.2,Data1.2
 1   1   10   'A'    93    'A'    55
 1   2   10   'A'    55    'A'    93
 1   1   12   'A'    88    'B'    66
 1   2   12   'B'    66    'A'    88
 2   3   102  'C'    14    'A'    22
 2   4   102  'A'    22    'C'    14
 2   4   112  'D'    15    'B'    43
 2   3   112  'B'    43    'D'    15
```

Essentially, there are 2 unique ID1s associated with every ID0.

Data is sampled periodically.

I would like to make the original data frame 'wider' by adding more columns so that each row contains information from the other ID1 from the same time period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
grb = df.groupby(['ID0', 'Time'])
df['Data0.2'] = grb['Data0'].transform(lambda ts: ts[::-1])
df['Data1.2'] = grb['Data1'].transform(lambda ts: ts[::-1])
```

what is this basically doing is, based on your statement that

> there are 2 unique ID1s associated with every ID0.

it groups the data-frame by `['ID0', 'Time']` and reverses the specific columns; if there are exactly 2 unique `ID1s` in each group, the data-frame will be expanded by the values from the other `ID1`;

```
>>> df
   ID0  ID1  Time Data0  Data1 Data0.2  Data1.2
0    1    1    10   'A'     93     'A'       55
1    1    2    10   'A'     55     'A'       93
2    1    1    12   'A'     88     'B'       66
3    1    2    12   'B'     66     'A'       88
4    2    3   102   'C'     14     'A'       22
5    2    4   102   'A'     22     'C'       14
6    2    4   112   'D'     15     'B'       43
7    2    3   112   'B'     43     'D'       15

[8 rows x 7 columns]
```

*final edit*: to do both columns together, you may try below; note that `.values` is necessary in here:

```
>>> grb = df.groupby(['ID0', 'Time'])
>>> df2 = grb['Data0', 'Data1'].transform(lambda obj: obj.values[::-1])
>>> df.join(df2, rsuffix='.2')
```

Comment: It always seems so obvious once you know the answer! This works great except I have quite a few columns and a for loop over them would be slow. Is there anyway to speed this up for many columns.

Comment: @WillBeauchamp i did a final edits for doing the columns together;

Comment: I found that simply merging and then deleting unwanted rows worked very quickly. Before one of your edits you suggested this.